# Internet Explorer 8 doesn't pass session cookie for ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, session

I have simple php application, it works on all browsers except on IE8 beta 2, problem occurs when I try to update table field using Ajax call (jQuery post method). Using IE8 debugger I figure out that IE8 doesn't send session cookie so php scripts redirects to login page instead of executing requested action.

What can I do to make this work.

Edit:
I  haven't  mention that i was using  Code Igniter so i have solved this problem by replacing Code Igniter default session implementation with native one. Code igniter default session implementation uses cookie to store all data.

Comment: Does IE 8 send the cookie on normal request?

Comment: On normal request works ok, but after ajax request it clears cookie.

Comment: CodeIgniter's Session implementation sucks

Answer (score 9):

Yesterday I had similar problem and found the solution. I hope this will help someone else also.

**Problem:** Suppose there's a website **www.somewebsite.com** and IFRAME inside it whcih loads php file from my server, **www.myserver.com/welcome.php**. Website was loading successfully as well as my welcome page and it showed something like "Hello Bob", so it successfully found user and logged him in.

Afterwards my JavaScript was making AJAX calls to another PHP file, and response was kind of in "not authorized" state, so SESSION data was completely missing. After page refresh, everything was working correctly. And this was happening only under IE8!

I thought that problem was with sending session cookies to the server, but when I installed [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I found that IE8 was sending cookies as well as PHPSESSID correctly, but server was kind of unable to detect correct SESSION object. Another strange thing was that 2nd time server sent following header:

**P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"**

but first time no. After adding that header manually in PHP script, everything worked like a charm!

Then, when I googled that "p3p abracadabra", I found following web site:

http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies

**Conclusion:** Make sure that you're sending the header on every page that sets a cookie.

And this is not **only** related to **IE8 + PHP** combination, same problem happens in case of **IE8 + ASP.NET**, **IE8 + JSP**, etc.

Comment: this was the solution for my non-frame jsonp cross-domain request that was not sending cookies. gracias!

Answer (score 6):

I don't have IE8 myself, but your cookie might be blocked by Internet Explorer's strange security policies. A possible workaround can be to employ [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) (which is also the method for getting cookies working inside an IFRAME).

Generating the right P3P policy can be a bit of work, but you should be able to find the information you need at http://www.p3ptoolbox.org/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE8 RC1:

1)a user goes to the login page and a blank session cookie is set
2)The user logs in and a validated session cookie is set and javascript opens a new window and closes the current window.
3)The new window is opened and contains a blank session cookie.
4)The user is redirected to the login page

I changed step 1 so that the blank cookie was not set - I only send the session cookie if its been validated. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble getting IE8 to use SSL Certificates (PK12) files as a means of authorization. If I want to protect a directory and force a matching web certificate to be present in the browser before granting access. It works fine with IE7 and all versions of Mozilla - just not IE8. It has rendered my wife's dictation system useless. One other thing I noticed is that when it sets the PHPSESSID cookie, it list the domain as .net and not mydomain.net.

Answer (score -3):

As a workaround, you can embed the SessionID as a parameter on the uri.

See [passing session id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) in the php manual.