# Passing variables between PHP modules loaded with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session, scope

I'm using jQuery to load a PHP module, in "deferred" mode, however the jQuery loaded module cannot access variables of the "main" PHP module. It looks like it can't access session variables too.
Is there a simple, quick and safe way to achieve this?

This is the code used to load the "deferred" page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery("#sidebarfeat").one('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
        if (isInView) {
            // element is now visible in the viewport
            jQuery("#sidebarfeat").load("/wp-content/themes/tgv1/featured.php", "",
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if(textStatus == 'error') {
                    jQuery('#sidebarfeat').html('There was an error making the AJAX request');
                }});

          }
        });

</script>
```

The code above uses jQuery inview plugin, however the problem lies into the PHP environment, it looks like the 2 PHP modules are running in "separated" environments....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't keep state between multiple requests. This means that standalone PHP cannot store variables in memory between requests. Sessions are saved to disk (by default), config files needs to be reparsed, etc.

If you want to keep variables between the two requests, you can use [sessions](http://php.net/session), or you can [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) your variables and pass them again through jQuery.

Server-wise, your XHR request is the same as if you requested the page in your browser. It's a completely different request.

As for not being able to access session variables, you need to make sure that you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) (with possibly the proper [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name) call before, look at your cookies to figure that one out) in your fetched script as well.

---

**EDIT:** Using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) is relatively easy. First, prepare all your variables you want to pass into a associative array, then call [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
$myVars = array();
$myVars['important'] = 'very';

$myJsVars = json_encode($myVars);
```

Then, in your `<head>`, assign `$myJsVar` to a JavaScript variable.

```
<script>var PHP_VARS = <?php echo $myJsVars; ?>;</script>
```

When you call `.load` in jQuery, pass in your variable as the second parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery("#sidebarfeat").one('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
        if (isInView) {
            // element is now visible in the viewport
            jQuery("#sidebarfeat").load("/wp-content/themes/tgv1/featured.php", PHP_VARS,
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if(textStatus == 'error') {
                    jQuery('#sidebarfeat').html('There was an error making the AJAX request');
                }});

          }
        });

</script>
```

`featured.php` will now be able to access those variables via `$_GET`.

Comment: I have tried to use sessions, however if the website will run in a cached environment, where the pages will served as static files, sessions functionality will be lost.

Comment: I see json_encode will "stuff" some values in a particular format. 
How will I pass those json_encoded values to the PHP module being loaded from jQuery?

Comment: What a rookie I am! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Nice but you mixed up session_name() with session_id(), session_name() only sets the name of the cookie (PHPSESSID by default) while you want to pass the current session ID.

Comment: @Capsule: With the proper [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name), a call to [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) will open the proper session. Cookies are sent when doing a XHR request.

Comment: Not in every case and/or with certain browsers (begins with a I and ends with an E ;-)). Trust me, I've seen cases where it's not transmitted and it's always safe to pass the session_id as well. And you probably don't want to change the session_name if it wasn't change in the "master" page.

Comment: @Capsule: In a cached environment, you are asking for trouble if you pass the `session_id()`. And I did say *"possibly a call to `session_name()`"* considering the WordPress environment used by the OP. I also never had trouble with IE not sending cookies in a XHR.

Comment: Of course you don't want to cache session dependant scripts ;-) I'll try to reproduce that bug about cookies not transmitted with XHR. I have to admit I've never investaged that much why it was not working in certain cases.

Comment: That might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483445/ie8-doesnt-pass-session-cookie-for-ajax-request but I've never used beta or RCs of IE. Anyway, the security settings of IE are so messed up I guess it could happen in every setup.

Comment: Andrew, one thing to point out: you need to use $_POST to retrieve data from your sample ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass your `session_id()` to the AJAX called script. Of course current variables will never be available in another process.

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass the relevant data through the `data:` parameter of the `.load()` method. Simply put the values into an array and serialize the array to a string.