# Asp.net ajax - losing session variables - Internet Explorer 8 and prior versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have been working on a legacy project (although C#) and trying to solve a session problem that have been encovered for years. It hapens on IE8 and prior versions. On IE9, Google Chrome,  Firefox and Safari works fine.

In other words, we have a management software that works fine on all browsers. But there is a specific page that makes tons of Ajax requests, and in some point it loses the session data.

I have checked for cookie problems with Fiddle but they are always sent and the same.

These clues make us think that the problem is within the application. But if we remember the problem occurs just in IE8 and prior versions we think the issue is probably in the browsers.

We also use a legacy Ajax library. And the problem mustn't be there as many of our aplications 
use it and they doesn't have the same problem.

- We are using IIS7 with State Server

I'm almost out of ideas. I hope you have some.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483445/ie8-doesnt-pass-session-cookie-for-ajax-request

Comment: There are no problems with cookies, they are always sent.

Answer (score 0):

Losing session state can be result of the application error. But if you claim that this happens only on IE8 and older versions, this could not be the case...
So I would suggest you to use page ViewState instead of session state. Let me know if did the trick for you?

Here is sample how to create propety based on page viewstate, just make sure you have enabled viewstate on page level:

```
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["MyProperty"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["MyProperty"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I fear I won't always have access to this property as the session data is set and retrieved within some libraries. And also, the Ajax library is implemented to access methods of simple classes (they doesn't extend Page or Control).

Comment: You can call server side function from javascript. Inside this function there will be no problem accessing session (if problem is inside legacy Ajax library not actual application).
You can access session inside static method like this:
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: Eric just let me know if you need further info and sample code how to make javascript call to server method. I will post you if required.

Comment: Gregor, the application does that in the ajax methods and also within some libraries. I mean, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session always used in the ajax methods. The problem is that it doesn't work in IE8 and older versions. When we use Chrome, FireFox or even IE9 session data is always present. And also the Page.ViewState would not be enough as session loss logs the user off.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Using Fiddler, I saw a very suspect request for "/". There was something requesting for the site base URL. And I remembered that the default page of this particular web application kills the session data, in other words calling the login page also means to log the user off.

After some hours of debugging and sniffing I found what was making such request.

There is a javascript function that creates some image tags. Some times those tag were created with an empty address, in other words the src property of the img tag was a string with 0 legth.

It must be an **IE8 and older versions bug**, as they request the website root instead of not requesting anything. Maybe it's not a bug, but this behavior is certainly unexpected.

Phew! I still can't believe I found it.